# SMB File Transfer Manager application for Windows?

Tags: windows, samba, file-transfer, server-message-block

I'm in the process of transferring very large files over an unreliable network connection using normal SMB (windows share folder). Of course, using Windows Explorer means that any time that connection is interrupted, all progress were lost, and any files that were in-process  were corrupted.

Does it need to be this arduous? Is there an equivalent of a download manager that can actively manage the pushing of data out to an SMB share and reliably pause/resume if the network connection falters?

Comment: Using the phrases "large files" and "unreliable network connection" with the acronym "SMB" in the same sentence is likely cause for much heartburn and headaches. Good luck with it, but beware that SMBv1 sucks like a vacuum cleaner over lossy or latent network links.

Answer (score 2):

Just found [RichCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog) as I searched a little more. Will mark complete if this turns out to solve my problem.

Update: RichCopy is pretty slick, but the pause/resume functionality seems like a joke. Take this use case:

1. Initiate VPN connection
2. Initiate file transfer with RichCopy
3. Pause file transfer.
4. Disconnect & Re-connect VPN connection
5. Unpause file transfer in RichCopy

I'd expect RichCopy to just pick up where it left off, but instead it spat out a few network availability errors, silently gave up on those three files, and moved on to three new files. So now those three files will never make it across unless I remember to move them after it's finished. Not cool.

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck with a program called teracopy too. And they have a free version for home use.

http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php

We use it all the time for big copies or for coping files off marginal hard drives.

Answer (score 1):

You can still pull down the files using [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx). It has many options, including resumable downloads. It's not just good at the job, it was specifically created for it. Unfortunately the documentation isn't as good as it was before Microsoft adopted it as an official product.

Comment: Two points. "Pushing" files with Robocopy is more reliable if you are using backup mode (/B). You can still find the original Robocopy.doc file via Google, and its worth a read if you haven't seen it before. Wikipedia has a pretty good article on Robocopy ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy ) too.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use FTP for that. Any shareware FTP server like ServU is good enough, and since this is a one off copy, you can safely uninstall the server afterwards. 
Just make sure that the FTP server you pick supports resumable downloads, and that on the other side you use a good download software package (NOT IE/explorer). I found wget for windows quite good for this sort of thing

Comment: Fair enough, but this solution assumes I have significant access to the remote system. In this case, all I have is the Windows share.

Comment: ouch, in that case all you have is SMB, which I personally don't trust for large file transfers over WAN. 
Sorry I can't help, the other answers are probably the way to go then